# NullPointerException with ViewPager after the app has been killed

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager

I have 3 pages in a ViewPager: instances of Tab0, Tab1, Tab2. In the main Activity, I'm storing the instance of each tab in separte variables from the SectionsPagerAdapter's getItem() function.

I assume that ViewPager always initializes the current tab, the tab to the left of it, and the tab to the right of it.

These are my instances: `Tab0 t0; Tab1 t1; Tab2 t2;`

The app works fine initially. But if i press the home button (to trigger `onPause()`), kill the app from task killer (or assume that android itself has killed it), and open the app again, i get NullPointerExceptions in `onPageSelected` because `t0, t1 and t2` are now null.

This is my onCreate method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
                    getSupportFragmentManager());

            // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
            mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int pos) {

                    switch(pos){
                    case 1:
                       t1.lookup()
                        break;
                    case 0:

                    t0.doSomething();

                        break;
                    case 2:
                            t2.someThingElse();
                        break;

                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {


                }
            });


    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1,true);
}
```

This is my FragmentPagerAdapter (which is a nested class inside my Activity):

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment;

        switch(position){
        case 0:
            fragment = t0 = new Tab0();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = t1 = new Tab1();         
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = t2 = new Tab2();
            break;

            default:
                fragment=null;
        }


        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        if(fragment!=null)
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.T1).toUpperCase(l);
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.T0).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.T2).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html):
The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy **may be destroyed when not visible**.  Meaning when it comes back the fragments will be recreated for you but will not be the original ones(hence your loss of t* variables).  I'd take a look at overriding saveState and restoreState methods to see if you can add the logic for setting up what the t* variables.  If not perhaps in one of the other on* methods in the fragment.